# Move floor vent into the wall

Tags: heating, ducts

Currently right by the toilet in my bath there is a heating register on the floor.  I want to build a small wall at the same location and have the heat exit out of the base of that wall.

Is there a way to do that is within code?

Comment: Sure. Heat supplies routinely exit walls. I believe it needs to be ducted (as opposed to returns, which can be virtually any cavity). Did you have a more specific question?

Answer (score 1):

This should not be a problem. As far as I know, code concerns itself with how much airflow is available for each room, but whether it comes out of the floor or the wall shouldn't make a difference. All you need is something like this [rectangular elbow](https://www.homedepot.com/p/3-1-4-in-x-10-in-Short-Way-90-Degree-Rectangular-Elbow-90E3-25X10/100138324):

[image]

As long as you can find the right size to match your existing ductwork, this is really easy. If you can't find the right size at a big box store then try an HVAC supplier - the place the HVAC techs go to get their parts. If you know exactly what you need, they should be happy to help.